# Square API: Batch request to Subscriptions endpoint

Tags: square-connect

The Square [Subscriptions endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1-business/#navsection-subscriptions) works differently from other Square API endpoints. The url begins with `/oauth2` and requires a special Authorization header to be provided.

Because of these differences, is it possible to include a GET to the Subscriptions endpoint in a [Batch request](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1-business/#post-batch)? All of my efforts so far have failed.

---

Here is my POST body to the Batch endpoint:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "relative_path": "/oauth2/clients/MY_CLIENT_ID/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTION_ID",
      "access_token": "Client APPLICATION_SECRET",
      "request_id": "MyRequestID"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the response:

```
[
  {
    "status_code": "400",
    "type": "bad_request",
    "message": "invalid endpoint",
    "request_id": "MyRequestID"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the oauth API endpoints are separate from the rest of the Connect API, and aren't supported by the batch endpoint. If you need to make a lot of requests to this endpoint in a short period, you will have to dispatch them in parallel.